# Adding two buttons which are touching each other in Framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I want to add two buttons one below another in a FrameLayout but they should be touching. However, I am not managing to do this. Here is my code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytOptions"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_via_email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:text="@string/action_sign_up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "both should be touched" please? Should the buttons be next to each other? Or overlapping each other?

Comment: Neil buttons borders should be touched.Means i dont want any space between two buttons.

Comment: I've edited the question to make that clear, assuming my edits are accepted.

Comment: Hi VK.Dev, On that basis I've put an answer below - is it any help? Does it need clarification?

Comment: Use a TableLayout and add two buttons in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

to  get the output like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical `LinearLayout` instead...

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/imgLine"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_via_email"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
    android:text="@string/action_sign_up"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Nunu, but it shows some space between two buttons.I dont want that space that's why I used frame layout but i couldn't succeed.

Comment: you can control the spaces between both buttons by using weight and making the width to 0dp.@VK.Dev

Answer (score 0):

By using framelayout you are actually placing one image on another, instead use linearlayout with buttons width and height as wrap content,and avoid using layout weights of the buttons. 
Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks Sangihta, doesn't work, but it shows some space between two buttons.I dont want that space that's why I used frame layout but i couldn't succeed.Actually i want to show like grouped uitableview style of ios.

Comment: ok then try adding padding to one of the image such that the images overlaps after certain dpi

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the key answer is to use a LinearLayout to position the buttons next to each other. However, to a "touching" effect, you will need to do one or more of the following:

1. Change the padding on each Button.
2. Change the margin on each Button.
3. Change the button background image so that it goes right to the edge of the View area.

My preference would be to set the margins and paddings to zero and to set the image to be the effect you want:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgLine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- options 1 and 2 -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_via_email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="0dp" <!-- Set there to be no space between the content and the surrounding views -->
        android:padding="0dp" <!-- Set to be no space int the content area but between the content and the edge of the content area -->
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- option 3 -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:text="@string/action_sign_up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/my_background"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You will need to define my_background as an imagine the drawable directory or res. You may the section on 9 patch images from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TableLayout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:background="@drawable/button_style"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:background="@drawable/button_style"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Assign a drawable button_style to the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#38393B"/>    
<stroke android:width="0.5dp"  android:color="#8aaa"/>
<size android:width="120dp" android:height="80dp" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for me. Works in framelayout!